# Cant modify event.target.value its always 0

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using `Autocomplete` component from `Material-UI` and the only issue that I have it, since I am trying to couple it with formik, I need the selected value to be in the event (in `event.target.value`)

The `onChange` function for `Autocomplete`, receives 3 arguments, 2 of which is what I need, the `event` and the actual `value` selected on the `Autocomplete`.

The issue is that I can't set that `value` to the `event.target.value`, `event.target.value` just remains unchanged:

```
  const handleOnChange = (event, { _id }) => {
    const eventCopy = { ...event };
    eventCopy.target.id = substringToNthSymbol({
      includeFinalSymbol: false,
      inputString: event.target.id as string,
      occurrence: 1,
      symbol: "-",
    });
 
    eventCopy.target.value = _id; // <== eventCopy.target.value is still 0 after this line

    formik.handleChange(eventCopy);
  };
```

P.S. As you can see I am also modifying the id, since Autocomplete adds suffixes like autocomplete-0, autocomplete-1 and so on depending on what is selected and I need to keep the original id, so I am simply removing the `-x`.

I have also tried to work directly on the `event` itself, and I have also tried without modifying the `id` still no effect and `eventt.target.value` stays 0, but changing the `id` works!

```
      <Autocomplete
        options={options}
        id="autocompleteId"
        name="autocompleteId"
        getOptionLabel={({ name }) => name}
        getOptionSelected={(option, value) => option._id === value._id}
        onChange={handleOnChange}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <StyledTextField
            {...params}
            fullWidth
            label="label"
            value={formik.values.fieldId}
            error={formik.touched.fieldId && Boolean(formik.errors.fieldId)}
            helperText={formik.touched.fieldId && formik.errors.fieldId}
          />
        )}
      />
```

EDIT: This too does not work and I still get 0 instead of the value:

```
formik.handleChange({ ...event, event: { target: { value: _id } } });
```

Comment: formik.handleChange(eventCopy); this can be updated to: formik.handleChange({event:{target:{value:_id}}}); because that would be the required format for formik as you may not need other event properties.

Comment: @PrakashS didnt work, it started throwing errors, apparently it needs more than that, the type of input for formik.handleChange is an event

Answer (score 0):

From [Material UI Autocomplete Doc](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#controllable-states) :

> The component has two states that can be controlled:
>
> 1. The "value" state with the value/onChange props combination. This state represents the value selected by the user, for instance when pressing Enter.
> 2. The "input value" state with the inputValue/onInputChange props combination. This state represents the value displayed in the textbox.
>
> These two state are isolated, they should be controlled independently.

If you try to do `input.target.value = ...` you are probably missing one of the two values controlled by the autocomplete.

Comment: I do get my the values, they come in as a second argument to the onChange function, I cant modify the event.target.value field to set my own value to it and then send the whole event to formik. I have tried with both `onChange` and `onInputChange` both have always a 0 on the `event.target.value` field.